# Variadic template wrapper around tuple

Tags: c++, c++17

I am currently in the process of updating my language knowledge (to C++17). I was trying to get this code to compile using gcc and couldn't figure it out so I tried MSVC and clang and both seem okay with this code -- is there anything wrong with this bit of code?

gcc seems to be complaining about instantiating a tuple<> with no template parameters which is odd:

> prog.cc: In instantiation of 'C::C(U&& ...) [with U = {const A&, const B&}; T = {}]':
>   prog.cc:32:14:   required from here
>   prog.cc:12:49: error: no matching function for call to 'std::tuple<>::tuple(const A&, const B&)'
>      12 |         : container( std::forward(params)... )
>         |                                                 ^

```
#include <tuple>

struct A {};
struct B {};

template<typename... T>
struct C
{
    template<typename... U>
    C(U&&... params)
        : container( std::forward<U>(params)... )
    {}

    std::tuple<T...> container;
};

template <class... T>
C(T&&...)->C<std::decay_t<T>...>;

int main(void)
{
    const A a;
    const B b;
    C c2(a, b);  // <-- this fails on gcc, okay on msvc and clang
}
```

Comment: @xaxxon the issue is that he wants to know why it won't compile on gcc :)

Comment: Which version of gcc?

Comment: @francesco fails with 8.3 https://godbolt.org/z/uXQA_y

Comment: the problem seems to be:  `<source>: In instantiation of 'C<T>::C(U&& ...) [with U = {const A&, const B&}; T = {}]':` <== T is empty, so it's an empty tuple type.  Is there some sort of conflict of deduction guides or something?   I don't know

Comment: If you add a SFINAE friendy error, it seems to work (`template<typename... U, typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(U) == sizeof...(T)>> C(U&&... params)`, or even `std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(T) != 0>`)

Comment: Removing deduction guide make clang fails a similar way...[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5067cd6273a06e5)

Comment: unusually, this looks like a bug in gcc

Comment: @RichardHodges gcc has tons of bugs

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80438

Comment: @cpplearner: But the given workaround did not work. So I believe that is an additional problem. So it seems to be helpfull to create a new bug entry or add the code example from here to the exsisiting one!

Comment: @xaxxon: Not with unsiversal reference type. If you use `template < class... T>
C(T&...)->C<std::decay_t<T>...>;` it works also. So for me it seems a different thing

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/zo6oLT

Comment: @xaxxon: Thanks! Had a type in my local example.... works!

Comment: Unrelated, but a better way to write the deduction guide is just `template <class... T> C(T...) -> C<T...>` - the template deduction rules already do the decaying for you.